# Facebook SDK for tvOS: logout

Tags: facebook, logout, tvos, fbsdk

I'm looking for a way to logout user but can't find it.

```
FBSDKDeviceLoginManager
```

doesn't have corresponding method and there is no smth like "FBSDKDeviceSession" also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no helper method but you can manually clear the current token:

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
```

I've updated the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tvos) at with this example.